# What controls turning off during overheating on Linux

Tags: linux, acpi

I started experience overheating (I have a few possible troublemakers for it and the cause is separate question) but I wondered what controls handling of overheating?

Sometimes my computer:

- Halts properly ("System is going down NOW")
- Is halted by controller (screen turns blank, goodbye all not written to disk cache)

Hence my question - how to change behavior to hibernation and/or hybrid-hibernations (well - arbitrary command - from that point I could handle)? Is is possible to specify treshholds to increase safe limits?

Comment: The Linux kernel has built-in routines to turn off the computer based on the temperature sensors. My older motherboard (Intel D865GV) and CPU (Celeron D) do not have temperature sensor hooks in them, so the BIOS returns a spurious value.

The kernel reads this spurious value and will not allow the kernel to boot. 

I can not turn off this behavior in the BIOS.

lm-sensors is not part of the kernel and is an external utility.

Does anyone have a real solution?

Comment: @gilles Rubbish. The answer given does not work. This site becomes useless if you encourage the posting of incorrect answers without discussion.

Comment: @perspectoff: Discussing the validity of a specific answer should be done in the comments to that answer. Also, this answer was never accepted as correct so you shouldn't assume it will just work. Finally, what part of the answer is incorrect and doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, usually you can set this temperature in the BIOS settings and it depends on the CPU type - I presume your CPU is getting hot, not some other hardware part.
If you are running linux, you can always construct some script reading out temperatures from /proc/acpi/... files - you can find temperature information there on some systems.
Or you can use software like Lm_sensors which can also find temperature sensors. 
Then I guess you could construct script which reads out temperature and issue sync and shutdown early to avoid hard crash.